# The target CleanWebsitesWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, typescript

I am unable to successfully build my projects using the build-all script.

Other team members can build using it fine, what am I missing?

I can't find enough information about CleanWebsitesWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder on Google!

I can build each project individually in Visual Studio fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out the issue here!

I have both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 installed on my computer.

For a few of the projects being built, the wrong MsBuild was used, which caused an error declaring the target "CleanWebsitesWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder" as not found.